# how to change typing direction when hit enter?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Usually, in `textarea` or in a `contentEditable` when you hit enter after every line the box will expand from the bottom and the previews text will stay in it the same position, but what I want is the previews text goes up every time I hit enter while the caret stays in the same position just like the old typographer.
I tried to achieve that in the following way, but I find my self sometimes I need the textarea to be in a relative position instead of ***`absolute`*** position. So, are their alternative was to achieve that??

```
 <div className="App">
      <h1
        contentEditable
        style={{ left: "center", bottom: "200px", position: "absolute" }}
      >
        Hello CodeSandbox
      </h1>
      <h1 style={{ left: "center", bottom: "150px", position: "absolute" }}>
        __________
      </h1>
    </div>
```

[sandbox link] (https://codesandbox.io/s/spread-sheet-2syww?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: *what I want is the previews text goes up every time I hit enter while the caret stays in the same position just like the old typographer.* I ran your code and that is exactly what's happening ?

Comment: If you read the question, he wants it so the text area is not using absolution positioning

Answer (score 1):

With `max-height` and `overflow-y: auto` you can archive this.

```css
h1{
    font-size: 32px;
    max-height: 68px;
    background: #dedede;
    font-size: 32px;
    outline: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
Example with max. two lines of text:
<h1 contenteditable="true">Hello World</h1>
```

Comment: but the previous text goes behind the box ( it disappears)

Comment: I need the height to be flexible

Comment: There is one problem. More and more lines will increase the `h1` height. So you will come to a point where the hight is greater than the viewport's height. At least at this point you need to cap the height (something like `max-height: 100vh`). In this case a scrollbar is shown.

Comment: the `h1` used only for short content it can never be longer than 5 lines of text. I'm using it for the title of articles